How is the associator defined in the Eilenberg-Moore category of a monoidal monad?
Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a symmetric monoidal category and
$T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a commutative monad. Lemma 5.1 and Lemma 5.2 of Jacobs' semantics of weakening and contraction states that in the presence of coequalisers of reflexive pairs in $\mathbb{C}^T$ we can build a tensor $\otimes^T$ providing $\mathbb{C}^T$ with a symmetric monoidal structure.
How do we build the associator $\alpha:(\varphi\otimes^T\psi)\otimes^T\chi\otimes^T\cong\varphi\otimes^T(\psi\otimes^T\chi)$ for algebras $\varphi,\psi,\chi$ in $\mathbb{C}^T$?

An explicit construction of the associator is in Tensors, monads and actions, theorem 2.5.5.
A more conceptual proof would go something like this: by the Yoneda lemma, it suffices to construct an isomorphism $$\mathbb{C}^T((\varphi \otimes^T \psi) \otimes^T \chi, X) \cong \mathbb{C}^T(\varphi \otimes^T (\psi \otimes^T \chi), X)$$ natural in $X$. If we regard $\otimes^T$ as a representation of the multicategory $\mathbb{C}^T$, both sides should be in bijection with trimorphisms of algebras $\mathbb{C}^T(\varphi \otimes \psi \otimes \chi, X)$. However the universal property of $\otimes^T$ only dictates that it represent bimorphisms, and I am not sure how to close the gap. Someone else might have a better answer.

I suppose first you would have to define the unbiased (lax) monoidal structure on the monad $T$, so that we have $T (A_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes T (A_n) \to T (A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n)$ for all $n \ge 0$.

As Naïm Favier suggests, we should first construct the multicategory of $T$-algebras.
A commutative (strong) monad is the same thing as a (lax) monoidal monad: this is mentioned as Corollary 3.7 in the cited paper.
That means we have a natural transformation
$$\nabla_{X_1, X_2} : T (X_1) \otimes T (X_2) \to T (X_1 \otimes X_2)$$
($\textrm{dst}$ in the notation of the cited paper) satisfying various coherence and compatibility conditions.
But when we have a monoidal functor we actually also get
$$\nabla_{X_1, \ldots, X_n} : T (X_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes T (X_n) \to T (X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_n)$$
for all $n \ge 0$ (where $n = 0$ is simply the unit $I \to T (I)$) by iterating the above, so we have a multicategory functor.
Similarly, compatibility with the monad unit $\eta$ and multiplication $\mu$ means that these are (also) natural transformations of multicategory functors.
Henceforth, we may drop the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ is monoidal and just work with the "underlying" multicategory.
For $n \ge 0$ and $T$-algebras $(A_1, \alpha_1), \ldots, (A_n, \alpha_n), (B, \beta)$, a multihomomorphism $[(A_1, \alpha_1), \ldots, (A_n, \alpha_n)] \to (B, \beta)$ is a multimorphism $f : [A_1, \ldots, A_n] \to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for $1 \le i \le n$,
$$f \circ [\textrm{id}_{A_1}, \ldots, \alpha_i, \ldots, \textrm{id}_{A_n}] = \beta \circ T (f) \circ [\eta_{A_1}, \ldots, \textrm{id}_{T (A_i)}, \ldots, \eta_{A_n}]$$
as multimorphisms $[A_1, \ldots, T (A_i), \ldots, A_n] \to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$.
(If $n = 0$ then this condition is vacuous, i.e. a multihomomorphism $[] \to (B, \beta)$ is just a multimorphism $[] \to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$.
The definition in the cited paper is ostensibly the case $n = 2$ but seems to have confused $\textrm{id}$ and $\eta$.)
Note that $T (f)$ is a multimorphism $[T (A_1), \ldots, T (A_n)] \to T (B)$ in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. $\nabla$ is implicit when we work with $T$ as a multicategory functor.
In this multicategory language, the theorem is that when $\mathcal{C}$ is a representable multicategory and has sufficiently nice reflexive coequalisers, then the Eilenberg–Moore multicategory defined above is also representable.
At least, I presume this is so – there are many details to check – but the point is that a representable multicategory "is" an unbiased monoidal category, and extracting unitors and associators from an unbiased monoidal category is easy.
(The hard work is probably hidden in the definition of "representable"; I gather that representability is not just about finding a natural bijection between $[X_1, \ldots, X_n] \to Y$ and $X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_n \to Y$ but also $[X_1 \otimes X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n] \to Y$ and so on.)
